# Two-column book with `mwbk` messes up Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, two-column, mwcls

If I remove the redefinition of `\chapter@toc` below, the table of contents entries end up without a number, and other error messages appear.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{mwbk}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter

\renewcommand*\chapter@toc{%
    \ifHeadingNumbered\typeout{\thechapter}\fi
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
        \ifHeadingNumbered
        \mw@seccntformat{\thechapter}%
        \fi
        \HeadingTOCText}}%

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\Blinddocument
\addtocounter{chapter}{10}
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes, I guess that's the best thing to do. Perhaps I found the solution, or just a workaround, I just wanted to find out why it didn't work before.